# jQuery MultiStep Form: Return to Previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the multistep form here in a Chrome Extension: https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz

I perform a JavaScript API call to login on Step 1 of the form, and if the login info is bad, I'd like to return to Step 1. Otherwise, I'd like to move to Step 2.

Is there an easy/succinct way to accomplish this? I added IDs to each fieldset and tried the following with no luck:

```
previous_fs = $("step1fs");
previous_fs.show();
```

Here's my login API call:

```
function login() {
    $.post("XXXXX",
    {
        ServerAction: "STEP4",
        username: document.getElementById('username').value,
        password: document.getElementById('password').value
    },
    function(data, status){
    if (data == "Login failed.") {  

        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Login failed. Check username and password.";
        //Return to Step 1
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
            //response parsing goes here
            //go to step 2

            };
    })
    };
```

Per a comment below, I've created a function called next below. I replaced "this" with the parent element. I'm attempting to call it with "next();" but nothing is happening. Console shows nothing:

```
  function next(){
if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $("<input type='button' id='step1btn' class='action-button' value='Next' />").parent();
next_fs = $("<input type='button' id='step1btn' class='action-button' value='Next' />").parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
    'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
    'position': 'absolute'
  });
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
```

};

Comment: In the codepen, they have a `$(".previous").click(function(){});` You can take everything out of that function and define as it's own function.

Comment: See my edits above, please. @NathanClement

Comment: Ah, it looks like that function has a `this` parameter in it. you will need to point that at the element that contains the "previous" button (it used to be based on the button that you clicked)

Comment: See my edit above. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. :) @NathanClement